# Splice digit format on ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I have cell with value

> 1234567

How to re-format to be like this

> 1.234.567

update: ok thx solved, this my code

```
.filter('custom', function ($filter) {
    return function (value) {
        return $filter('number')(value);
    };
}
```

Comment: you could use custom filter to format this..or can use `ui-mask` library

Comment: the same way you apply it on html..could you add some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`number`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) filter:

```
$scope.amount = 1234567;

{{amount | number}}
```

You should setup your correct [locale](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n).

Comment: If you load the correct locale you can also avoid the replacement.